# DNS server settings differ between 'Device Info' & 'DNS'

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dns, thunderbird

My Sagecom (TalkTalk) router Primary & Secondary DNS settings differ depending on where one looks.

1. Under 'Device Info' Primary is `79.79.79.79`; Secondary is `79.79.79.80`.
2. Under 'DNS' Primary is `208.67.222.222`; Secondary is `192.168.1.1`.

I get frequent DNS server errors when using Thunderbird on a Windows 10 desktop necessitating restarts and wonder if changing the DNS Server to, say Google `8.8.8.8` might be a solution, but which of the the above settings do I change? Why are they different between locations?

The router provides data to my TalkTalk TV box, could that be an impediment to changing DNS?

Comment: ok, so you push out IP addresses and DNS server addresses to your personal devices from the router using the DHCP protocol. I believe those are the settings you describe as "DNS", though usually they will be part of your DHCP settings. just like you push settings to your devices over DHCP, your ISP does the same thing for its devices, so the "device information" is the information your ISP is pushing your router for its WAN interface, and the settings under "DNS" are the settings you are pushing down. you should be able to change the "DNS" settings, but its likely you cannot change the WAN DNS

Comment: What model is your Sagecom? Can you add a screenshot of the Device Info page to your post?